# How to deal with an temporarily unavailable mq-server?

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-artemis

I have two simple spring-boot apps. The first one sends messages to an artemismq-server and the second receives the messages. This is basically working fine, but what are the best practices on dealing with an unavailable mq-server on the sending side?

I haven't found much information about this topic. Only the basic "catch the exception and handle it yourself" stuff. I would prefer to automatically buffer the messages (persisted) on the sending side and resend it (periodically / as soon as the mq-server is available again). But I did not find any general solutions for it.

Now I am wondering if I am completely on the wrong track...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you want the message sender to continue operating normally even if the remote broker is unavailable then you need a buffer of some sort on your sender.

You can implement the buffer many different ways, but in your case I would suggest configuring a local instance of ActiveMQ Artemis that uses a [core bridge](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/core-bridges.html) (or perhaps [federation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/federation.html) for more complex use-cases) to forward messages to the remote broker. Your sender would send messages to the local instance and the local instance would forward those messages to the remote broker. You could [embed](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/embedding-activemq.html) the local broker in your application or it could run as separate process on the same machine as the sender.